# .NET MAUI: How to change the navigation bar colour of an app that just uses ContentPages?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

In .NET MAUI, a `ContentPage` doesn't have the `BarBackgroundColor` property, unlike the `NavigationPage` and `TabbedPage`. Is there another way to change the nav bar colour, such as a property in the `Styles.xaml` that I'm not aware of?

And by nav bar, I mean the bar on the bottom with the back button and such, not the top bar with the title.
[image: navigation bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `AppShell`. You can access those properties like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Shell.BackgroundColor="Red"
             x:Class="MauiApp.MainPage">
```

**EDIT**

Now I understand your question better, here is your answer:

On your solution explorer, go to:

> Platforms > Android > Main Activity.cs

You need to call `OnCreate` method here.

You can start typing "override OnCreate" and select the OnCreate method from that menu. After that you can set those colors.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);
    Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question to be more specific, I'm talking about the bottom nav bar as seen in the image in my question.

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer. I hope this solves it. Note that you call "OnCreate" method only once.

Answer (score 5):

I know is a little bit late but mabe it can help some others too. You can go to Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml and there you will find that:

```
     <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Blue100Accent}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    <Setter Property="IconColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
</Style>
```

And in your App.xaml.cs:

```
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `App.xaml.cs` or `MauiProgram.cs` you could write something like this to change the bottom navigation bar color on Android:

```cs
#if ANDROID 
   Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Colors.Blue.ToAndroid());
#endif
```